# Create Pull Request Excluding Old Commits on bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket, pull-request, git-commit

I would like to create a Pull Request excluding the old Commit (the struck through in RED) on Bitbucket.

[image]

Is there some method in https://bitbucket.org/ to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you should have started the branch from master so there wouldn't be the changes you dont want. you can do that now and just cherry pick your new changes and it should wor

Comment: In general (and I guess in BitBucket too though I haven't used it), a PR from source branch to target branch will include all commits on the source branch that are not yet on the target branch. If you remove the commit from your source branch and force push the branch, the PR should get updated to no longer include that commit. In your case, if the commit you wish to remove is the tip commit then perhaps repoint your branch back one commit and force push it. If it's not the tip commit you'll need to rewrite (`rebase`) your branch. (You could create a new branch and PR also.)